# ggplot2: combine positioning commands position_nudge and position_stack

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I want to produce a plot with stacked bars and shifted 50% to the right so the ticks are between the bars.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~Station, ~Direction1, ~Direction2,
             "A", 432, 485,
             "V", 543, 345,
             "B", 435, 457,
             "Q", 0, 0)

df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels=unique(df$Station))

df = gather(df, Direction1, Direction2, key = "Direction", value = "Passengers")
```

The first plot shows the the stacked bars as desired:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Station, y = Passengers, fill = Direction)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack())
```

The second plot has the bars shifted to the middle between the ticks but the bars are now plotted behind each other:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Station, y = Passengers, fill = Direction)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_nudge(x = 0.5))
```

How can I combine the 2 positioning commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should serve your purpose. You don't have to specify the position if you want `position_stack()`, as it's the default position argument in `geom_bar` / `geom_col`.

(Incidentally, you may want to consider switching from `geom_bar` to `geom_col`, as the latter uses `stat = "identity"` by default. Less typing.)

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x = as.numeric(Station) + 0.5, y = Passengers, fill = Direction)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Station",
                     limits = range(as.numeric(df$Station)),
                     breaks = unique(sort(as.numeric(df$Station))),
                     labels = levels(df$Station))
```

[image: plot]